# Import all sheets from a folder into the current workbook and import them after the open sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet called Master File (.xlsm)
[path = /Users/charliekeegan/Desktop/AWS Test/Master File.xlsm]

What i want to do is import all the sheets from a folder called "Tester1'
[path = /Users/charliekeegan/Desktop/Tester1].

And i want to import all of these AFTER the first sheet in the file (called sheet 1 - but i will be changing that).

I need this as a macro because it will be done programatically each day.

Also if possible, if i could delete the files from the folder after they have been imported that would be amazing!

Comment: import sheets from folder??? Do you mean workbooks?

Comment: What have you researched / tried already? Post your code.

Comment: @Gadziu yes i mean workbooks.

Olly everything i tried seemed to be overly complicated and didnt work. I'm not new to vb/excel and was under the impression that this would be a simple fix